# 'str' object has no attribute 'call' when converting .model to tflite file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror, tensorflow-lite

I have been following this tutorial to perform voice command recognition for a couple words on my ESP32: https://github.com/atomic14/voice-controlled-robot

I was able to train my model and have the "fully_trained.model" file: ["fully_trained.model"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKb6A.png)

Currently I am trying to convert the .model file into the tflite file, however I am getting the "'str' has no attribute 'call'" error: [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhxhN.png), [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaoNw.png), [Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odu5z.png)

My tensorflow version is 2.6.2 and python version is 3.10.

Unfortunately, I do not have 10 reputation points yet, so I couldnt embed the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` you need to pass the `tf.keras.Model` instance, not the path to the saved_model folder.

Use `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()` instead and pass the path to the "fully_trained.model" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You've passed `"fully_trained.model"`, with quotation marks, as an argument to TFLiteConverter. That's a string. Give the model a name and pass that name as an argument to the converter, without quotation marks.